# pkg-config: platform-neutral way to find out where to install my .pc file?

Tags: build, cross-platform, makefile, pkg-config

How do I know where to install my *.pc* file?  These files are put in different places on different operating systems.  The goal is to be able to use something like `$(INSTALL) mylib.pc $$(pkg-config --pcdir)` in the install target.  I thought `pkg-config` would be able to tell me somehow, but can't find anything.

I'm looking for a "standalone" solution usable in plain Makefile (must not require support from autotools or similar).

Comment: If you install a *.pc file, it MUST be installed in $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/pkgconfig.  The user of your package has the privilege and the responsibility of setting DESTDIR and libdir appropriately, and if your package ignores what the user specifies then your package is broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Evidently there is now a way to do this:

```
pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
```

Found in this [bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14975#c4) (see comment #4). The current man page appears to document this.

**Original answer:**

Horrible hackish solution (assuming bourne shell):

```
pkg-config --debug 2>&1 |grep Scanning | sed -e 's/Scanning directory //' -e "s/'//g"
```

This may give you more than one location.

**edit** by @just somebody

shorter version

```
pkg-config --debug 2>&1 | sed -ne '/Scanning directory /s///p'
```

and to stop after the first directory:

```
pkg-config --debug 2>&1 | sed -ne '/Scanning directory /{s///p;q;}'
```

Comment: @just somebody: Congrats! Very nice (but hacky, but so is my solution :-P) approach to use debug messages. :-P

Comment: - Using autoconf for portable feature probing -- check.
- Using automake for portable building -- check.
- Using libtool to abstract away the peculiarities of share library handling -- check.
- Using pkg-config to portably discover compiler flags -- check.
- ...
- Relying on an undocumented implementation detail of pkg-config that may or may not be there, defeating the whole struggle for portability -- check.

-1.  Still looking for a portable and non-insane way to do this

Comment: @fstd you should check the current man page -- there is now a way to do this.

Answer (score 14):

As of pkg-config 0.24, you can do "pkg-config --variable=pc_path pkg-config".

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14975

Answer (score 3):

it should go into ${libdir}/pkgconfig (ie ${prefix}/lib/pkgconfig)

basically if you install libraries and they go in ${libdir} then your .pc file should be in ${libdir}/pkgconfig and nowhere else.

Comment: it'd be nice if the real world was this simple, but for whatever reason, FreeBSD puts pkgconfig files in ${prefix}/libdata/pkgconfig.  it's stupid, but it's there.

Comment: in that case look at what stuff like glib does

Comment: FreeBSD is certainly following the pattern; they've set libdir=${prefix}/libdata

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, for a stock `pkg-config` installation (for version 0.23), there is no way to extract the default "pc path", short of running `strings` on the binary (e.g., `strings /usr/bin/pkg-config | grep '/usr/.*/pkgconfig'`).

If you are able to install a custom build, just patch it to write out the value of `PKG_CONFIG_PC_PATH` when run with the appropriate option.

Another option, which probably won't help you (but that I'd mention anyway for completeness), is to set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable when calling `pkg-config`.

Comment: "impossible": that's been my conclusion as well.  not an answer i'd be overly happy with, but unless harry potter shows up, i'll accept this.